# Fallout 4 - Materials not being shared

Tags: fallout-4

I have the Local Leader perk installed and have been enjoying building up settlements all over the Commonwealth & the Island, sharing the resources though supply lines. Recently I noticed though that some of my settlements are not actually sharing materials. For example, I have 2 shipments of concrete in the workbench at Sanctuary, which is connected to all settlements:

[image]

But I am unable to build anything with concrete at Longfellow's Cabin & Dalton's Farm (both on the Island). I thought at somepoint that both these Island settlements were connected to the rest of the grid but it appears they are not. I just started building up Longfellow's Cabin, and assigned him to the Supply Line duty, but it appears there is no concrete shipment avaialable (I actually cant build anything out of concrete).

So my questions are:

1. Is the Island actually capable of being connected to the Commonwealth through supply lines?
2. What can I do to make sure settlements are actually connected?

Comment: Did you actually connect your island settlement with something on the mainland? I can't really tell from your illustration. But yes you can share between far harbor, mainland, and nuka world.

Comment: I think what happened is that I nuked a couple of connecting settlements, and with that the supply connections were broken (even though the connection lines were still present on the map). I essentially had to rebuild 2 entire settlements, and wait around for the caravan settlers to appear so I could reassign them to something else. Its been a major pain in the ass, but I think I am making progress. I am still not 100 if this is the cause for the Island settlements though. But to answer your question, yes the island settlements were connected to Commonwealth ones.

Comment: Ya, something is not right. I just connected Graygarden to Oberland Station and the shipments that are present in the Graygarden workshop inventory are not showing up in Oberland Station, even after the new supply line shows up on the map.

Comment: So it seems while the nuclear material that I have at one settlement is not showing up in the other, I am still able to use the material to make things. What a broken ass system they designed for this. It would be helpful to at least know what is available.

Comment: Do you use settlers or robots for supply lines?

Comment: @A.bakker settlers

Comment: @KalamalkaKid the only thing i can think of is that one of the settlers is in combat, if  supply line settler is fighting the supply line is (temporary) disabled. But this can only happen if you are near the settler.

Comment: Wait -- are you expecting to _see_ the physical material from settlement A in the workshop in settlement B? It doesn't work like that. If you stash something at Sanctuary, you won't magically see that thing in Red Rocket; but you'll be able to use it to build stuff.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Yes that is the confusing part. I see many people asking about this. I understand now, but wish the devs would have through this through better.

Comment: OK I thought that the problem was that you connected the two settlements, but you couldn't _use_ the material stored in one settlement when building in the other. :)

Answer (score 1):

> What can I do to make sure settlements are actually connected?

Caravans do get occasionally stuck and indeed there are glitches that break them down, it's not a very stable mechanic and I have no definite answer what's causing it. I have some vague memory about power losses in one settlement causing problems, because beacons etc go offline. Or maybe it is missing something else like food or water, so that the caravanner can't work. If a settlement is attacked and you don't respond, raiders will break things up. Including, power, food or water. You'll have to repair the resource if that happens.

You can also try to hunt down the person assigned as caravanner and re-assign them the same route. If they get involved in fights with raiders etc that might also cause problems, but that only happens when the player and the caravanner are both near hostiles.

Also avoiding excessively long routes seems wise, I never had much problems when I just connected all settlements to the closest one and built up a network like that, rather than having most of them go to lets say Sanctuary.

> Is the Island actually capable of being connected to the Commonwealth through supply lines?

Yes you can connect to Longfellow's cabin in Far Harbor and also to the gas station on the Nuka World DLC map. It works like any other trade route, though I always picked a settlement near the DLC map. For Far Harbor, the nearest would be "Coastal Cottage" and for Nuka World, "Sunshine Tidings". Not sure if it matters.

Answer (score -2):

You need to work both ways sometimes theres a glitch where some items appear to link due to modding at this piont i have ten penny one way to sactuary and i cant share workshop items hope that helps